# HTML button (part of button is dark)

Tags: html, css

I have a button in my application and currently its very basic:

```html
<button style="height:150px;width:150px;border-radius:10px;">Hello,World</button>
```

Which means it has the default HTML CSS effects used w/it. I was attempting to change it w/CSS but everytime I make the button bigger, there's always this dark side on the right and bottom side..I'm not sure why. If I change it back to its default, its not there.

Here is the JSFiddle:

http://jsfiddle.net/htzgak6g/1/

I'm referring to the right side and bottom side. They seem darker to me than the other sides. All I want to do is have some type of button with rounded corners and a nice shade of color.

Comment: people that ask things like this have 63 Reputation and people like me solving way harder problems for others have a bare 50 because most wont accept the answer. Stack devs pls, do something

Comment: @KhrisAzuaje solve some of the easier problems and you'll get votes

Comment: Check out my profile, the easiest problems solved which never got accepted because people like @halapjos1 take us just like mere google robots ready to solve everything for them in exchange of nothing. But thats not the truth, we want something, we're craving Stack rep.

Comment: @KhrisAzuaje Dang, so much hate man. Yeah, I admit its an easy question but you don't need to go around commenting on things that you think are easy. I'm sorry I'm new to HTML/CSS so I don't have the knowledge that YOU might have but you don't need to go around saying shit man. If you don't have anything good to say then keep that shit to yourself. Don't be such a little pessimistic individual about getting Stack rep.

Comment: @KhrisAzuaje Just because your answer isn't getting nominated as the best answer doesn't mean that its not helping anyone. I've seen so many answers that aren't the best answer yet I've learned so much. Be happy to be able to share your knowledge w/the world, don't just be hating on people if they ask an easy question and they don't pick your answer. Stack rep is fake...clearly, your a knowledgeable individual and you should be satisfied with that. If having an 'X' number of stack rep is going to make you happy, then you have soul searching to do man.

Comment: thats true, thanks for reminding me that part of StackOverflow @halapgos

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that the browser appends default style to the elements which are marked by `<system>` in `Firebug`. You can use the [**Selectors style panel**](https://getfirebug.com/wiki/index.php/Selectors_Side_Panel) to view all the styles added.

[image]

As Toni said, you will need to use [`reset.css`](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/meyer-reset/) to ignore such styling. But for this specific problem, set the `border-color` to be transparent.

```css
button {
  border-color: transparent;
}
```

```html
<button style="height:150px;width:150px;border-radius:10px;">Hello,World</button>
```

Answer (score 4):

This is because buttons come with some basic default browser styles that are still taking effect because you haven't over-ridden them.

In this case, adding `border: none` will remove the border and the dark colour. (http://jsfiddle.net/htzgak6g/2/)

Look at a [reset css](https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/meyer-reset/) to solve these problems and give a consistent blank slate across browsers.

Comment: Cool, thank you so much! I thought I needed to override some things, but I wasn't sure what exactly.

Comment: @halapgos1resets are really useful for this, they get rid of all those things that leak through

Comment: Okay, I'll make sure to look into it as well! Thanks again!

Answer (score 2):

Just add `border-style:none;` like so:

```
<button style="height:150px;width:150px;border-radius:10px;border-style:none;">Hello,World</button>
```

[Here is your updated **JSfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/htzgak6g/3/)

Comment: Thank you so much! Really appreciate it!